# How can I download Ruby gems without installing them or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working from a Windows machine I can't install anything on, and am trying to get the Ruby gems for a Linux machine not connected to the internet. The Windows machine does not have Ruby on it, only the Linux machine.

How can I get the needed gems for the Linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download them from https://rubygems.org/ on the Windows machine.

You can transfer them to the Linux machine via USB or similar.

Comment: I've had no luck with the 'download' links. For whatever reason they don't work, I get a page of jumbled characters

Comment: @mcfinnigan that just allows me to dl the htm page, which opens to the same result

Comment: @Dave Right-click and save as the download link on the ruby gem page. It will download a ".gem" file.

Comment: @Cereal it should, but for whatever reason on this PC it does not, instead I get a .htm file

Comment: @Dave You can't be getting an htm file because there isn't an htm file there. For example: https://rubygems.org/downloads/libv8-3.16.14.3.gem

If you're manually giving it the htm file type when saving, it will still be a gem, just rename it. Otherwise, I have no idea what you're downloading.

Comment: You can alternatively visit the source for the gem clone/download it and build it yourself, e.g `gem build some_gem.gemspec`

Comment: @Cereal it seems as though the extension was being changed when the download was started, probably because the file extension wasn't recognized, I tried renaming the extension and will see if that works

Comment: @Cereal after renaming the file it is recognized as a gem on the linux machine, thanks